# ODBC or OleDB database drivers under Azure App Service

Tags: azure, odbc, oledb, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm investigating what's involved in deploying an ASP.NET MVC web application to Azure as an App Service, using Web Deploy from Visual Studio 2015.

The MVC web application uses SQL Server for the identity database in the standard fashion, so I can see how to point that at an Azure-hosted database server.

In addition, it has some 'legacy' data in DBF files in the App_Data folder, accessed on my development PC via OLEDB.

This scenario is obviously going to fail on deployment because whatever box(es) the site ends up hosted on won't have this OLEDB driver installed.

Is this a complete non-runner or is there some way of installing the driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install ODBC or OleDB drivers when using App Service, you need to look at Virtual Machines.

Comment: That's what I figured - didn't want the overhead of a full VM if possible but there we go ...

Comment: hi @CSharpRocks, is this still valid now? We still can't install ODBC driver on an App Service running on Linux?

Comment: @Kelvin It seems that an ODBC driver is already available in Azure functions (it should be available for App Services too)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/559327c2-6bd9-4337-bfe4-5d5d8273a813/install-odbc-driver-for-sql-on-function-app-linux?forum=AzureFunctions

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use Windows Containers on Azure App Service in which you have control over what drivers or custom software to install.

Please check the quick start to run a Windows Container in App Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container