# Azure web app crashes when initializing mongo DB client

Tags: mongodb, azure, ssl, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I have created Cosmos DB account with MongoDB driver and want to access it from flask server. Here is the simplest example I'm trying:

```
from flask import Flask
from pymongo import MongoClient


url = 'monbodb://<my_db_name>.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true
username = '<my_db_name>'
password = '<my_password>'
client = MongoClient(url, username=username, password=password)
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
    return 'pong!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I deploy it with git and at the end it says the deployment was successful. But really app has crashed because webpage is not accessible, saying "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.". I guess issue is with SSL, because removing '/?ssl=true' does allow access app webpage but it this case DB is not accessible! What is with issue and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to access my `mongo db` in my azure flask web app and it works well for me. You could refer to my working steps and codes.

***view.py***

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template
from jaygongflask import app
import pymongo

@app.route('/mongo')
def mongo():
    uri = "mongodb://<account name>:<your account key>@<account name>.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb"
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
    db = client['db']
    coll = db['coll']
    doc= coll.find_one()
    return render_template(
        'mongo.html',
        title='Mongo',
        message='Mongo query result.',
        queryResult = doc
    )
```

Publish your flask project and add the `web.config`.

[image]

***web.config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Here, I use python361x64 extension. So I run the command `python -m pip install pyodbc` in KUDU.

[image]

***Get query result***

Access the url `http://***.azurewebsites.net/mongo` .

[image]

More deployment details , please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publishing-to-azure).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello, Jay. Thank you for your replay, I'm trying your solution. Could you please tell me which one of *.config files should I edit? Currently I see few possiblities: 1) web.2.7.config in "/d/home/site/repository", 2) web.2.7.config in "/d/home/wwwroot" and 3) web.config in "/d/home/site/wwwroot".

Comment: @RailSuleymanov You need edit the one which is stayed with your project(may be the No.3 /d/home/site/wwwroot you mentioned).  please see my additional screenshot.

Comment: apparently we’re in different time zones, because I didn’t have chance to check yet. I’ll let you as soon as I have one to try. But at the time of my yesterday reply I wasn’t able nor to create files (touch get-pip.py) nor to install packages in Kudu CMD, so I guess it’s gonna be challenging...

Comment: @RailSuleymanov Never mind. You could refer to the details from my previous case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155223/install-odbc-driver-to-azure-app-service/47197435#47197435 . Any concern or you stuck with one step,please let me know.

Comment: @RailSuleymanov Anyway, you could refer to the cases I answered previously, I believe you could make it out!  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8198946+touch+get-pip.py

Comment: Hi, I used python27 extension and could finally create get-pip.py and install pymongo along with adding web.config... What do I do next? How should I restart the app? I guess, these settings are different from virtual environment created by Azure so should start be different?..

Comment: Well, I could launch the app with command "python ../site/wwwroot/main.py" and now it runs. I'm not sure if this is a legitimate approach, but anyway, thank you very much!