# django image upload cannot import name _imaging

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, python-imaging-library

uploading image in DJANGO web app hosted in azure is not working it is showing me an error

> error cannot import name _imaging

but it works fine in local machine. I tried installing different version of `pillow` but it still displaying the error

i have a model in django that accepts text and image i am actually trying this from django admin and also it works fine locally i dont know what happed when i ship the code it displays the above error.i think the problem is with the azure

Comment: Please add the code you've used to the question.

Comment: i dont write any code it is the django module that uses the pillow

Comment: If you haven't written a single line of code, which existing program are you running?

Comment: Please add such information to the question, not in any comment.

Comment: You probably have both PIL and Pillow installed on the server, but locally only Pillow.

Comment: is PIL installed by default in azure or ... and if that is the problem what shall i do

Comment: @Robel Any updates now?

Comment: thank you guys for helping me.  i found the problem it is the version of pillow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my previous case : [install odbc driver to azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155223/install-odbc-driver-to-azure-app-service/47197435#47197435) to install pillow package in your azure django app.

[image]

In addition , as @Andrey said you could check if PIL and Pillow both installed in your django app via KUDU. Please refer to this case :[ImportError: cannot import name _imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340698/importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging).

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows install pillow from .exe package