# Install Hive ODBC driver on Azure Function App in App service Plan

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I am working on a Python Application deployed on Azure function App. I want to access Hive from my function App. For that i have to install HIVE ODBC Drivers on the function app. Is there any way to install them?

Comment: Do you want to use Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx) to install Hive ODBC driver on Azure Function App?

Answer (score 0):

Please check @Joaquín Vano's (Principal Software Engineer Manager at Microsoft) reply in this case: [ODBC or OleDB database drivers under Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441052/odbc-or-oledb-database-drivers-under-azure-app-service)

> One possibility
> is to use Windows Containers on Azure App Service in which you have
> control over what drivers or custom software to install.
>
> Please check the quick start to run a Windows Container in App
> Service:
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?